# Фамилия Шереметьев

Tags: этимология, ономастика

А от какого слова происходит знаменитая дворянская фамилия Шереметьев?

Answer (score 2):

К слову "шеремет". Трудно предположить иное. )))
Слово тюркское, означает "быстрый, скорый, легкий(в движении)".
На русской почве стало применяться преимущественно к лошадям с подобными качествами.